# Rails - Auto generated readable ERD with large database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erd

I have a database with ~50 tables and many complicated relationships, I want to generate an ERD of my DB so I use a gem named `rails-erd` (source: https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd).
However because of the large DB so the result ERD is not readable and it looks like a spider net. I wonder is there's any other gem out there which you can suggest me to use ?
Thank you.

Comment: `it looks like a spider net.` If your DB model is complex enough, what else do you expect?

Comment: Hi emaillenin, I want it to be easy to view & understand the relationship (for new guy who recently joins to project), or at least adding some color into the ERD file, currently `rails-erd` only have black & white

Comment: try grouping a smaller set of related tables and generate diagram only for that

Comment: Or maybe try http://railroady.prestonlee.com/

Comment: @Niklas thank you, this gem works like a charm, it's perfect